# How can I make NPC stop when player is near? Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im a new programmist. I was trying whole day to make my npcs stop, but I may be to dumb for it.
They were no longer walking, no reacting on player and other stuff like this.
I couldnt find answer on my question, so please dont be mean to me.

I tried to call player as a target, but then I couldnt define what target is. I tried also something like if target is not in range then move, but they are no longer moving at all.
Maybe my code will help anyone to help me.

```
public bool playerIsClose;


        if(!playerIsClose)
        {
            if(isWalking)
            {(...)}

     private void OnTirggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            playerIsClose = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTirggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            playerIsClose = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this, I set on both of them colliders 2d and set isTrigger to true.
But my npc isnt even noticing me .
Maybe i forgot to add something somewhere?
Cause everything I tried is above.
Maybe i should add somethinng?
things i skipped in my code is things that just make my npc  move.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of the name of your functions, you currently have

> OnT***ir***ggerExit2D

instead of

> OnT***ri***ggerExit2D

([see the official documentation to be sure](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html))

Comment: ... My god. Thanks bro. I think its time to make my characters bigger so I can easier find typos.

Comment: No worries it happened/will happen to all of us!